# Terms and notation for the sets of upper and lower bounds of a given set.

Tags: notation, terminology, order-theory

I've seen this notation for the upper and the lower sets generated by a subset $X$ in a poset $P$:
$$
P\uparrow X =\{\,y\in P\mid(\exists x\in X)(y\ge x)\,\},\qquad
P\downarrow X =\{\,y\in P\mid(\exists x\in X)(y\le x)\,\}.
$$

I am looking for terms and notation for the sets
$$
\{\,y\in P\mid(\forall x\in X)(y\ge x)\,\}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\{\,y\in P\mid(\forall x\in X)(y\le x)\,\}.
$$
Is there any?

I would also be interested in the notation for the sets of strict upper and lower bounds
$$
\{\,y\in P\mid(\forall x\in X)(y > x)\,\}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\{\,y\in P\mid(\forall x\in X)(y < x)\,\}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the [Dedekind-MacNeille completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93MacNeille_completion#Definition) of a partially ordered set I have seen the notation $X^u$ and $X^\ell$ for the sets of upper and lower bounds of $X$.